# WCF not allowing large list . Throwing "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request." exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have a list which has 9 fields. When i pass A smaller list (say 50 rows) the application is working fine. If i pass a larger list my service is throwing the exception "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request." exception. please help me solving this issue.

My Web config is as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Windows">
            <!--<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />-->
    </authentication>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600"/>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors >
        <behavior name="Behavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
        openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
        openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>            
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
        openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/ErrorService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" contract="ErrorServiceReference.IErrorService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/SecurityUserService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService"
        contract="SecurityUserServiceReference.ISecurityUserService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService" />          
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and my wcf config is as below

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>

        <add name="DEFAULT"  connectionString="server=DEV1;Port=52;database=UTIL;User=ara;password=me;Charset=iso_1;Connect Timeout=100" />

      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="DEFAULT_SERVER" value="UAT"/>
        <add key="DEFAULT_DATABASE" value="UTIL"/>
        <add key="DEFAULT_PORT" value="480"/>
        <add key="DEFAULT_USER" value="fator"/>
        <add key ="DEFAULT_PASSWORD" value="U212ajUyODY="/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

          <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600"/>

      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Behavior">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>

        </services>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

I modified my service web config with endpoint and binding as below. but still I am getting the same error

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="DEFAULT"  connectionString="server=DEV;Port=52;database=UTIL;User=ar;password=me3;Charset=iso_1;Connect Timeout=100" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DEFAULT_SERVER" value="UA"/>
    <add key="DEFAULT_DATABASE" value="UTIL"/>
    <add key="DEFAULT_PORT" value="45"/>
    <add key="DEFAULT_USER" value="fr"/>
    <add key ="DEFAULT_PASSWORD" value="Y="/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600"/>

  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="Service.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                  contract="Service.IService1"
                  name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetaDataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <timeouts openTimeout="00:30:00" />
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="Service.ErrorService" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService"
                  contract="Service.IErrorService"
                  name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetaDataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <timeouts openTimeout="00:30:00" />
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="Service.SecurityUserService" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService"
                  contract="Service.ISecurityUserService"
                  name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetaDataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <timeouts openTimeout="00:30:00" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
        openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
        openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
        openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I guess The endpoint and the binding i defined explicitly are not getting used by the service. please correct me if i have configured The service wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following tag

The problem in your application is that you are using different contract names for service.
In Web.Config you are using contract name as "ServiceReference1.IService1" for Service1 and in service web config you are using contract name as "Service.IService1". May be it will solve your problem.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters ="All"/>  
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration ="Default" name ="Service.IService1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding ="basicHttpBinding" contract ="ServiceReference1.IService1"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>                
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>      
    </services>
    <behaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="Default">

          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls ="100" maxConcurrentSessions ="100"/>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="Web"></behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
```